# How to activate touch pad in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-touch

Could anybody suggest me how to activate touch pad  in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `Settings` -> `Mouse & Touchpad` then click the toggle button with an external mouse.

See screenshot below:

[image]